# How can I change the default program for viewing pictures and photos?

Tags: default-programs

or any other program while i'm at it, ubuntu built-in utilities are nice but there are better.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

### The Easy Way

The first is to right click on a picture in your file manager, select Properties and then navigate to the Open With tab, then select the application you want and click Close:

[image]

### The Second Way

You can also right click on files you want to change by right clicking on them selecting Open With -> Other Application ...

[image]

From there you will have the option on what program you want to use to open that file, select your preferred viewer from the list:

[image]

You need to make sure you check the bottom checkbox.

Comment: how do you do this from the cli?

Comment: Exactly what I needed to have InkScape as my default image viewer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) to do this.

Once you have installed it, *Applications -> System Tools -> Ubuntu Tweak -> System -> File Type Manager -> Image*.

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but I've been voted down for suggesting it before so I didn't :(

Comment: @RolandTaylor Yeah, someone down voted me too. Real lame to not tell someone *why* you are down voting them.

Comment: This is certainly the best answer for *images* since there are so many types and other methods are slow. Thanks DoR!

Answer (score 10):

Go to the:

**System Settings > Details > Default Applications**

And set **Photos**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can go to system->preferences->preferred applications in your menu to change many of your applications, but you can also right click your files (like image files), click properties, and then open with. You can choose a default application from here for your file type :).

There may be a gconf entry for the image viewer, but I'm not sure where it is, so maybe I will add that to my answer later.

Comment: There's no photo option in Preferred Applications.

Comment: " **to change many** " and " **but you can also right click your files (like image files), click properties, and then open with. You can choose a default application from here for your file type :).** "

Answer (score 0):

Next question: how to change the default app for a batch of filetypes?

This annoying default filetype associations problem annoyed me so much that I wrote an article about it! It is a somewhat clumsy solution but it works.

[How to change default programs on Ubuntu](http://www.johannes-eva.net/change-the-default-application-ubuntu-linux/)

Hope it helps!