# How can I make another pdf viewer default for pdf files?

Tags: pdf, default

How can I make another pdf viewer standard for pdf files in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can right-click on a .pdf file, then go to 'Properties' --> 'Open with' tab and select the application that you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can also used this simple utility ubuntu tweak which you can use for any application [ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com). You can use it to change the music player for any mime-type. after installing go to filemanager..

Comment: thanks for the advice. I know the Ubuntu tweak, but didn't know that it has such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

right click on a pdf file, click on "Properties", go to "Open With" tab and select the program you want. You can change the default program for any kind of file using this method. Here is a similar question: [How can I change the default program for viewing pictures and photos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15418/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-for-viewing-pictures-and-photos)