# Why doesn't Preferred Applications include an image application?

Tags: gnome-control-center

You can use "Preferred Applications" to set your media player, web browser, etc, but why does it not provide an option for images?

You can use [Ubuntu Tweak to set the image viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15418/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-for-viewing-pictures-and-photos/15424#15424) for all of the different image types, but it would be nice to have it built into Ubuntu.

Is there a technical limitation? (If it's possible with various audio/video types, I don't see what makes images more difficult.)

Or is it just a too much to do and not enough resources problem?

Comment: better served as a bug report, not a question.

Comment: @Roland: I was more curious _why_, but a bug is a good idea https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/751756

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading some [mailinglist posts](https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/msg03856.html), I think the Preferred Applications dialog was probably implemented to control what applications are launched for the media keys on your keyboard (web key, mail key, play/pause keys). The other two settings (terminal and accessibility) are also used by hotkeys.

Of course none of these options are exclusively for hotkeys, but I guess that's where their use comes from.

Comment: All of these settings are best included in a dedicated control centre. This is one area where gnome falls down a lot.

Comment: Sometimes the separation doesn't make sense, but it has benefits. Aside from avoiding a colossal and confusing settings monster, I can type "preferred" into gnome-do and have that application open. Of course, if I could open the preferred pane of a settings application the same way, I'd be pretty happy.