# How to change the default program for pdf (only for current user)

Tags: default-programs

On Ubuntu 10.10 I would like to change my default pdf viewer to acroread.

I do not have sudo privilidges, so I want to make this change for my own user only. Acroread is already installed.

Comment: Does Right Click(pdf)->properties->Open With->Acroread->Choose default work?

Comment: @Capt.Nemo Yeah it does. Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the default program for viewing pictures and photos?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15418/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-for-viewing-pictures-and-photos)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

To set the file associations :

1. Right Click on the file
2. Choose `Properties`
3. Go to the *Open With* tab.
4. Choose your file viewer. For eg. `acroread`.
5. That's it. Click on close.

[image]

Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15418/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-for-viewing-pictures-and-photos/15434#15434) for an alternative method.

Comment: Why it doesn't let me add acreader? It's not even among the possibilities

Comment: I don't think Adobe is detected because of the way it is installed. See bernaulli's answer for a workaround.

Comment: If it's not being detected, then "sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/acroread.desktop" and change the line "Exec=acroread" to "Exec=acroread %U".  Then it should show up on the list as described above.

Comment: @Gsxr1k: Thanks, that works for me in Fedora 26, while bernaulli's method didn't work.

Comment: Still valid information for 22.04 :-)

Answer (score 17):

To set the default program to pdf

1. `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`
2. Add **`application/pdf=acroread.desktop`** or **`application/pdf=AdobeReader.desktop`**

The correct name of the `.desktop` file can be found in `/usr/share/applications/`

This will set the pdf default program as adobe reader

Comment: I edited the post without being connected so I don’t know if it will go through peer review. Anyway, **on ubuntu 16.04** the file to edit is `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

Answer (score 6):

An update for Ubuntu 13.04.  I am, however, using Gnome fallback session with no effects.

I wanted to use Foxit Reader 1.1 for my default PDF viewer, but I couldn't add it through right-click in file manager and "Open With," right-click properties and "Open With," or through  "System Setting" → "Details" → "Default Applications".

What did work for me was "Ubuntu Tweak":

1. The PDF default is under the "Admins" tab, then click the "Applications Centre".
2. Look for "All" in the "Category" column on the far left.
3. Scroll down to find the "PDF" file type and the "Associated Application".
4. Double-click to change (brings up a window) where you can "Add" an application through one provided or find your own.

Comment: This worked for Adobe Acrobat Reader, under **Ubuntu 13.10**.

Answer (score 5):

An update for recent Ubuntu and Gnome. You can change default app setting on `nano ~/.config/mimeapps.list` for more information see https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en

Comment: '... recent Ubuntu...' means which version of `Ubuntu`?

Comment: This is the correct location for (K)Ubuntu 22.10.