# Prevent Google Chrome from opening PDF files?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium, pdf

I'm using Google Chrome (not Chromium) on Ubuntu 14.04.

While I could configure Chromium to not open PDF files, and just prompt to save them instead, I couldn't do it with Google Chrome.

No matter what I try, it insists on opening PDF files in its rather pathetic viewer when I click on them.

Is there any way to prevent Google Chrome from opening PDF files?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want Chrome to stop opening PDF files and save them instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Open this URL `chrome://settings/content`, scroll down and enable last checkbox. (*Open PDF files in the default PDF viewer application*) Your PDF files will be downloaded, not opened.

Check [this post](https://malwaretips.com/threads/new-method-to-permanently-disable-chrome-pdf-viewer-2017.68014/).

Comment: This still opens the files though. I just want to save them (I could, in Chromium). Definitely an improvement though (+1 for that)

Comment: I don't know, if there is another way. Check [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Jw3tiGDaIl4).

Comment: And you can always use `right mouse click` and `save link as` instead of opening file.

Comment: Yes, that'll work in most cases, although sometimes you only get redirected to a PDF (Save-As gives some "url" or "html" file)

Comment: ... actually, with this setting, right-clicking opens the PDF file (in the default viewer) anyway.

Comment: If you disable association between PDF files and your default viewer in your system, files will be only downloaded, not opened.

Answer (score 0):

this will help for sure. The current update of google chrome has enabled default pdf opening and has not given any option to disable it.

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/61641/how-to-change-the-default-program-for-pdf-only-for-current-user][1]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1209226)