# Downloads from Chrome or any shortcut from Places menu opens with Evince

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, google-chrome, folder

When I try to open a file that has been downloaded from Chrome, or any folder in the menu bar "Places", `evince` opens with an error.

The error does not occur when I open a file with a particular program from the command line (ie: `gnumeric myfile.xls`) or if I open and navigate from Places>Computer, although it does occur with Places>Home Folder, Places>Desktop, etc.

For example, this is the result of clicking on Places>Desktop:

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Checking the settings for a given filetype to see if preferred
  application is 'evince', but it is not. I have followed [this
  guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15418/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-for-viewing-pictures-and-photos).
- Checking the settings on Chrome, but I can not find anything related to it.
- removing evince: received 'Failed to execute default File Manager'...

Comment: Might be an ugly hack, but try uninstalling evince.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo it might have been an ugly hack that didn't work, but it pointed me to the answer posted below. Thanks. I'll give the bounty to you if you write it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to change your default file manager. Either follow the steps at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager), or simply type

```
 exo-preferred-applications
```

at the command line, select the 'utilities tab' and switch to your favorite file manager (e.g. Nautilus, Thunar).

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling `evince`

```
sudo apt-get remove evince
```

With evince no longer on the machine, check what response chrome gives to opening files, and it might point you in the right direction.